why my cookies is not recorded in the network tab, but on the postman its recorded
Im following some tutorial but my cookies is not recorded in the network tab even I copy and paste the code, when I tried to register my user, I don't see my cookie on the network tab , but it successfully recorded in the database
my server
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import authRoutes from "./routes/user";
import authUser from "./routes/auth";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";


const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use("/apiv1/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/apiv1/auth", authUser);
app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Hellow World!");
});

export default app;

this is my register user routes Register Routes
import { Request, Response } from "express"; // Import the types
import User from "../models/user";
import { generateToken } from "../utils/generateToken";
import { validationResult } from "express-validator";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const registerUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, password, firstname, lastname } = req.body;
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: errors.array() });
    return;
  }

  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({
      email: email,
    });

    if (user) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: "User Already Exist!" });
      return;
    }

    user = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
    });

    // generateToken(res, user._id);
    await user.save();
    
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { userId: user.id },
      process.env.JTW_SECRET as string,
      {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      }
    );

    res.cookie("auth_token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 86400000,
    });

    res.status(201).json({
      message: "User Registered Successfully!",
    });
    
    console.log({ message: "Generated Token", token });
    console.log({ message: "User sucessfully", cookies: req.cookies.auth_token });
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Something went Wrong!" });
  }
};

my register routes
const router = express.Router();

// //apiv1/auth
router.post(
  "/register",
  [
    check("firstname", "First Name is required").isString(),
    check("lastname", "Last Name is required").isString(),
    check("email", "Email Name is required").isString(),
    check("password", "Passowrd with 6 or more characters !").isLength({
      min: 6,
    }),
  ],
  registerUser
);

export default router;

my cookie is generated successfully

Postman


It depends on how you make the request on the client side
